# In WordPress how do I pass multiple variables into the URL and retrieve them?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, get

For some reason I can only retriever the first variable, in this instance, "product_category" out of the URL http://localhost/coffeesite/?product_category=coffee&brand=bourbon .

I'm outputting javascript to confirm that I've set the variable, but again, only coffee will be alerted, and not brand. I'm using WordPress's 'get_query_var'. See code below:

```
<?php 
        echo '<script> product_category = "' . get_query_var('product_category') . '"; 
                       brand = "' . get_query_var('brand') . '";
                       alert(product_category);
                       alert(brand);
             </script>'; 
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated - I'm struggling to solve it!

Comment: don't do that. you're stuffing text from PHP directly into a js context. you are at major risk of introducing JS syntax errors. ALWAYS use json_encode() to guarantee that PHP produces something that's valid in JS. e.g. `brand = <?php echo json_encode(get_query_var('brand')); ?>;`.

Comment: thanks so much for the tip. Just curious as to why stuffing PHP into the js context would put it at risk for syntax errors, whereas json_encode does not?

Comment: because json is essentially javascript. e.g. `$foo = "Miles O'Brien";`, if you echo that into JS, you end up with `var bar = 'Miles O'Brien';`, which gives you a string termination error. encoding to json ensures that the entire php string becomes a valid javascript string. consider json_encode to be the javascript equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string() for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are testing, maybe you could test the php directly?  The function get_query_var is just a wrapper for the generic php array $_GET.  You should have these values available at $_GET['product_category'] and $_GET['brand'].  But instead of assuming everything is where it is supposed to be, why not check what you actually have?

```
<?php 
    add_settings_error("var-test", "var-test", implode(", ", array_keys($_GET)));
?>
```

Disclaimer: I am a Drupal developer, not Wordpress, but they are both php.
I am using the documented message tool here, for a little cleaner php code. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error
You could still use your javascript if you would like:

```
<?php 
    echo '<script> alert( '. implode(", ", array_keys($_GET)) .');
         </script>'; 
?>
```

Second possibility.  The reason for using a wrapper function instead of the raw core is for what it provides in that wrap.  My normal assumption is sanitation and security filters, which are poor for testing but essential for production environments.  However, with a little bit of reading on the function you are using, it says it only returns values for known query objects and if you are using custom variables in the url you should register them.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var
Have you registered "brand"?

Comment: Thank you! I had to register brand as you mentioned in the second possibility.